# Cosmos DB select with where clause with max date

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I want to select item with max date.

I have `select`:

```
select d.MaxDate from (select max(c.ChangedDateTime) MaxDate FROM c WHERE AND c.IsLatest = true) d
```

and the result is:

```
[
    {
        "MaxDate": "2020-07-16 12:23:57"
    }
]
```

And now I want to select row with max date:

```
select * FROM c WHERE IsLatest = true 
WHERE c.ChangedDateTime = (select d.MaxDate from (select max(c.ChangedDateTime) MaxDate 
FROM c WHERE AND c.IsLatest = true) d)
```

Result is empty, it should return one row with the date `2020-07-16 12:23:57`

---

When I do select like that:

```
select * from c where c.IsLatest = true AND c.ChangedDateTime = '2020-07-16 12:23:57'
```

it returns exactly one row which I want to have, so I think that there is something wrong with subselect because it returns array with object `[{"MaxDate": "2020-07-16 12:23:57"}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just selecting one row after sorting?

```
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE IsLatest = true 
ORDER BY c.ChangedDateTime
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The result is the same: `[
    {
        "ChangedDateTime": "2020-07-16 12:18:34"
    }
]`

Comment: @Robert . . .  What do you mean the result is the same?  Your question says that the result is empty.  If the other columns are `NULL` that would appear to be what is in the most recent row.